# Closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$.

Tags: general-topology

How do I argue that the closed ball of radius 1 isn't compact in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}=\{ (x_1,x_2,\cdots) : x_i \in \mathbb{R} \ not \ all\ x_i \neq 0 \}$?

This set isn't metric space, so I can't use the fact that a compact set in a metric space is closed and bounded.
Perhaps it isn't closed in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this isn't a metric space, whats "a closed ball of raduis 1" then?

Comment: In addition to defining "closed unit ball" you also have to specify what topology do you put on $R^{\infty}$ (there are many!).

Comment: The topology here is $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{\infty} \ is \ open \ \Leftrightarrow U \cap \mathbb{R}^n \ is \ open \ in \ \mathbb{R}^n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, then what do you mean by closed unit ball?

Comment: $D=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty} : ||x||=\sum x_i ^2 \leq 1 \}$

Comment: This really isn’t clear, even after the comments to date. Your definition of $\Bbb R^\infty$ says that it consists of all real sequences that have at least one term that’s $0$; is that really what you meant? Or did you mean all real sequences that have only finitely many non-zero terms? Also $\Bbb R^n$ is not a set of infinite sequences of real numbers, so it’s not a subset of $\Bbb R^\infty$ by either definition of $\Bbb R^\infty$; thus, if $U\subseteq\Bbb R^\infty$, then $U\cap\Bbb R^n=\varnothing$ for all $n$. Are you using the symbol $\Bbb R^n$ to mean the set of sequences that are $0$ ...

Comment: ... after the first $n$ terms?

Comment: I don't understand what's difficult here. $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ consists of sequences that from some point all the entries of  the vector are zero. Sorry if I didn't write it properly, I am just typing as it's written in my notes.

Comment: That isn’t what the definition given in your question says. For that you want $$\left\{\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots\rangle:\exists m\in\Bbb Z^+\forall n\ge m(x_n=0)\right\}\;.$$ That’s what I guessed, but it definitely isn’t what you wrote. And the other point still stands: $\Bbb R^n$, as it is normally defined, is not a subset of this $\Bbb R^\infty$. What you’re (mis)calling $\Bbb R^n$ is really the set of infinite sequences $\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ such that $x_k=0$ for all $k>n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I’m going to fix the definitions:

$$\Bbb R^\infty=\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle:\exists m\in\Bbb Z^+\forall k\ge m(x_k=0)\}\;,$$

the set of all real sequences that are eventually $0$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we define

$$R_n=\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle:x_k=0\text{ for all }k>n\}\;.$$

There is a natural bijection $\pi_n:R_n\to\Bbb R^n:\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\mapsto\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$. A set $U\subseteq\Bbb R^\infty$ is open iff $\pi_n[U\cap R_n]$ is open in the usual topology of $\Bbb R^n$. Finally, $$D=\left\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in\Bbb R^\infty:\sum_{k\ge 1}x_k^2\le 1\right\}\;,$$ and the problem is to prove that $D$ is not compact.

---

With that out of the way, here’s a large HINT:

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $x^{(n)}=\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, where

$$x_k^{(n)}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }k=n\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;;
\end{cases}$$

clearly each $x^{(n)}\in\Bbb R^\infty$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$U_n=\left\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle:\frac12<x_n<\frac32\text{ and }|x_k|<\frac12\text{ if }k\ne n\right\}\;.$$

- Show that each $U_n$ is open in $\Bbb R^\infty$.

Now let $E=\{x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$.

- Show that $E$ is closed in $\Bbb R^\infty$. Conclude that if $D$ were compact, $E$ would also be compact.
- Show that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $E$ with no finite subcover, thereby showing that $E$ is **not** compact.

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow and after I'll understand it I'll approve it. Thanks.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: You’re welcome.

Comment: In the definition of $R_n$ you meant that $x_k = 0 $, right?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: Oops. Yes, I sure did. Fixed; thanks.